# More specific constraints in derived classes using JSR-303

Tags: java, bean-validation

Lets say there's a class `Money` that has fields amount and currency:

```
class Money {
    private int amount;
    @NotNull Currency currency;
}
```

While `Price` is also money it introduces additional constraint: amount cannot be negative

```
class Price extends Money {
    // add more specific constraint for amount field: @Min(0)
}
```

Is it possible to express this using JSR-303?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a property level constraint should do the job:

```
class Price extends Money {

    @Min(0)
    int getAmount() {
        return super.getAmount();
    }

}
```